# How does the time complexity of the bubble sort algorithm result in O(n^2) regarding the way you calculate it?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, bubble-sort

I understand that why bubble sort is O(n^2).

However in many explanations I see something like this:

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ..... + 3 + 2 + 1
Sum = n(n-1)/2
```

How do you calcuate `Sum` from this part:

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ..... + 3 + 2 + 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: here's a proof of sum of n consecutive integers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-1234-cdotsn-fracn-timesn12

Comment: This is a mathematics question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the trick:

```
If n is even:
  n + (n-1) + (n-2) + … + 3 + 2 + 1
= [n + 1] + [(n-1) + 2] + [(n-2) + 3] + … + [(n - (n/2 - 1)) + n/2]
= (n + 1) + (n + 1) + (n + 1) + … + (n + 1)
= n(n+1)/2

If n is odd:
  n + (n-1) + (n-2) + … + 3 + 2 + 1
= [n + 1] + [(n-1) + 2] + [(n-2) + 3] + … + [(n - (n-1)/2 + 1) + (n-1)/2] + (n-1)/2 + 1
= (n+1) + (n+1) + (n+1) + … + (n+1) + (n-1)/2 + 1
= (n+1)(n-1)/2 + (n-1)/2 + 1
= (n^2 - 1 + n - 1 + 2)/2
= (n^2 + n)/2
= n(n+1)/2
```

For your case, since you're counting up to n-1 rather than n, replace n with (n-1) in this formula, and simplify:

```
   x(x+1)/2, x = (n-1)
=> (n-1)((n-1)+1)/2 
 = (n-1)(n)/2 
 = n(n-1)/2
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest "proof" to understand without deriving the equation is to imagine the complexity as area:

so if we have sequence:

```
n+(n-1)+(n-2)...
```

we can create a shape from it... let consider `n=5`:

```
n     5     *****
n-1   4     ****
n-2   3     ***
n-3   2     **
n-4   1     *
```

Now when you look at the starts they form a right angle triangle with 2 equal length sides ... that is half of `n x n` square so the area is:

```
area = ~ n.n / 2 = (n^2)/2
```

In complexities the constants are meaningless so the complexity would be:

```
O(n^2)
```